# TypeScript, re-use same function in different Phaser.States

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I've created a game using Phaser, and I want to "port" it over to TypeScript. I'm running into a problem when I want to call the same function from several different states.

Among a few other variables and functions, there is for example a music on/off function and a function to fade the entire screen to black. I want to re-use these in the different `Phaser.States` MainMenu, LevelSelect and Game. So I put them as global variables in the MyGameProj.Client namespace, however this gives an error `Cannot find name ..` when I call them from the MainMenu state.

I know global variables and functions are considered A Bad Thing, but my question is;
**how can I re-use one function in several different Phaser.States?**

I've tried adding the global variables and functions in my boot state, like so:

[Boot.ts]

```
module MyGameProj.Client {
    var SOUND_IS_ON = true;
    var MUSIC_IS_ON = true;

    function switchMusic(game, onoff) {
        MUSIC_IS_ON = onoff;
        // .. etc.
    }

    export class Boot extends Phaser.State {
        preload() {
            switchMusic(this.game, true); // no errors
            //.. etc.
```

But then when I try to access the switchMusic from my MainMenu state, it gives an error 'Cannot find name switchMusic'. However, they can be used and called from within the Boot state.

[MainMenu.ts]

```
module MyGameProj.Client {

    export class MainMenu extends Phaser.State {
        create() {
            switchMusic(this.game, true); // <- error; Cannot find name switchMusic
            //.. etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define variable/functions inside your own module/namespace, as you did with `MyGameProj.Client` then those are not considered global.

In order to use what you have in `MyGameProj.Client` from another namespace/module you'll need to prefix the function/variable with the path of that said module:

```
MyGameProj.Client.switchMusic(this.game, true);
```

Also, if both modules (`MyGameProj.Client` and `MyGameProj.Client`) reside in different files then you'll need to let the compiler know where to find `MyGameProj.Client`.
How to do that depends on how you load other scripts, you can either import it:

```
import * as m from "MyGameProj.Client";
```

or reference it:

```
/// <reference path="MyGameProj.Client.ts" />
```

You should read the [Namespaces and Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) and [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) sections of the official docs.

Comment: Thanks you for the very quick reply. I just started with TypeScript and figured namespaces and modules were the same thing, so I'll definitely check out the suggested links.